# Visual Studio 2019 - VB.Net - Incompatible Program

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019, compatibility

I author quite a complex Windows Forms App(.NET Framework), written recently in VB.Net using VS2019. One of my users recently had a problem where, after the latest Win10 upgrade, the program would not start. Re-installation made no difference. Right-clicking the .exe and chosing the "Program Compatibility Troubleshooter" resulted in a message "incompatible program".  Trying again some time later, the user reported that the program is now working, despite no further action taken.

My question: Why might a program be flagged as incompatible, and what can I do to stop this happening again?

Comment: With things like this, the first occurrence I make a note, second occurrence collect some more info about th context but only start actively looking into it if it happens a third time..

Comment: I assume there was no new window update in the meantime right?

Comment: Try running application in [Windows 10 compatibility mode](https://cn.bing.com/search?q=Windows%2010%20compatibility%20mode&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=windows%2010%20compatibility%20mode&sc=6-29&sk=&cvid=F048D73B69F4434BABEB814E9CBAA8C5)

Comment: All good points, thanks guys. Yes, Windows was updating, he said. Is there some type of Compatibility Tester, where you can show it a program and it says: Not Compatible Because...?